# How to trigger specific Angularjs UIClient application based on a server call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have an AngularJs application named "DataUIClient". Every month after the release of the DataUIClient in production we have a new version of this AngularJs application.

Every version of AngularJs application is tied to specific version of the Server. For example, if the server version is 12.0 then the Angular Application also must be 12.0.

However, According to the new requirement, what I need to do is to convert this AngularJs application as mobile compatible hybrid app using cordova which I have done. Now this converted cordova app, when we plan to host in play store or app store, if user downloads it then it should check the server version (let's say server version is 12.0) and load the appropriate version client (angularjs app which we converted through cordova) i.e. 12.0 version.

I should clarify here that we get to know the version of the server only after successful login into the application.

Now, How do I achieve this ?

**Tried Option** : I can keep upto three client versions under one directory structure and try and trigger the latest angularjs application which can define routes to navigate to previous version/s based on the server version.

**[outcome]**: The application is so tightly coupled in layers of directives, services and templates that the amount of changes I went through were humongous. That would not solve the problem.

I did look into the option of having multiple roots but there are too many changes involved in re-factoring the application as it is one humongous application.

Comment: This seems pretty easy, unless I'm missing something. When you login and are provided the version number, then dynamically load the correct JS that is hosted on that server. `https://www.example.com/scripts/{appVersion}/app.js`.

Comment: Actually this is a AngularJs application converted to mobile application using Cordova. So there is no version of client that is hosted anywhere.... it’s a hybrid mobile app

Comment: I realize how Cordova works. You can still host your AngularJS code on a server that you control then load the correct version after you login. Similar to how a CDN works.

Comment: @JM-AGMS : Actually this AngularJs application is not hosted in any single server. Every customer’s machine has their own separate AngularJs website client hosted and they can be on any version of the server.